# Lazy fetching in a new transaction

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jta

In this queue processing I wanted to put the sending itself into separate transactions to avoid rolling back the sent status. However I run into problem due to the closed session or detached entity at the lazy fetching.

This is my code:

```
// Before this is called queueToSend is fetched in a separate transaction

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void sendMails(List<QueuedMail> queueToSend)
{
    for (QueuedMail queuedMail: queueToSend) {
        sendMail(queuedMail);
    }
}

public void sendMail(QueuedMail queuedMail)
{
    System.out.println("Checking "+queuedMail);

    crud.getEntityManager().merge(queuedMail);

    Mail mail = (Mail)crud.find(queuedMail.getMail().getId(),Mail.class);
    System.out.println("mail id: "+queuedMail.getMail().getId());

    crud.getEntityManager().merge(mail);

    Boolean unsubscribed = false;
    Set<Campaign> campaigns = mail.getCampaigns();
    for (Campaign campaign: campaigns) {
        if (campaign.getUnsubscribedUsers().contains(queuedMail.getUser())) {
            unsubscribed = true;
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

The error is:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: dps.simplemailing.entities.Mail.campaigns, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

And comes first at the line:

```
for (Campaign campaign: campaigns) {
```

I thought it can be because the queuedMail is already detached, however I am trying to reattach both queuedMail and mail using merge, but it doesn't help.

Also maybe it's already in cache, and that is why it doesn't start a new session.

Basically I want it to do the same as before (before I added TransactionAttribute), but as a separate transaction within the loop. I don't think I should do any vendor-specific solution as it seems to be a trivial task.

---

Update:

I have done some research, and found that I have to use the result of the merge operation in order to reattach the detached entity. This changed the vendor-specific error (as using lazy loading properties of a detached entity undefined) to a vendor-independent error, and I think it shows the real problem.

The modified code is:

```
public void sendMail(QueuedMail queuedMail)
{
    System.out.println("Checking "+queuedMail);

    queuedMail = crud.getEntityManager().merge(queuedMail);
    Mail mail = (Mail)crud.getEntityManager().merge(queuedMail.getMail());

    Boolean unsubscribed = false;
    Set<Campaign> campaigns = mail.getCampaigns();
    for (Campaign campaign: campaigns) {
        if (campaign.getUnsubscribedUsers().contains(queuedMail.getUser())) {
            unsubscribed = true;
        }
    }
```

I have also changed the entity to define the cascade type:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "mails",cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private Set<Campaign> campaigns;
```

Now the error is this:

```
Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
```

What I don't really understand about this error is that the transaction should have been started as the class default is `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED`. The intention for setting the other methods to `TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED` was to start the transaction in this method. I am beginner in transactions and entity manager, so I will just continue research to understand it better, but maybe I get answer here sooner, or if I find the solution I will post it.

Comment: In Campaign you have relationship entities. It lazy by default or you set it default. Simple solution it mark it eith eager. Better you can load all lazy in session transaction on before  method call sendMails

Comment: The core problem here is not the lazy entity, as it's good as it is, I don't want to load it eagerly, it would be a simple solution, but it would decrease performance later. The problem here is that a transaction is already ended. I will update the question soon as I made some code changes that altered the error I get, so that it's more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the glitch, it's pretty tricky, enough to say, that no further research shown the real problem, but I got the answer during taking time out and walking.

As I told, the main idea for this method was that the `sendMails` has no transaction, while the `sendMail` (should) have a transaction, and this would have to provide one transaction for every item to be processed.

The error in the update shown to me that there is no transaction in the `sendMail`, and I were really confused about it.

The real reason is found in the fact that the bean is executed using a proxy. Normally this is done from outside of the bean itself. If the bean calls it's own method directly, the container doesn't have the chance to proxy the request, nor it can start a transaction.

The corrected code has an injection point in the bean injecting it's own instance, but using the container:

```
@Stateless
public class MailQueue {

    @Inject MailQueue mailQueue;

    // ...

}
```

And using this injection point one method can call the other method via the proxy:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void sendMails(List<QueuedMail> queueToSend)
{
    for (QueuedMail queuedMail: queueToSend) {
        mailQueue.sendMail(queuedMail);
    }
}

public void sendMail(QueuedMail queuedMail)
{

    // ...

}
```

With this solution the container has the chance to start the new transaction before the call to sendMail.